# xfce4-Terminal doesn't create a new pts session?

Tags: terminal, tty, xfce4-terminal

I'm running Openbox on Manjaro, and I've come across a peculiarity trying to use `write` and `wall` with some friends. I use xfce4-terminal as my preferred terminal emulator, and I was never able to get any messages using these utilities.

If I logged in and did not `startx`, I could communicate on the base tty just fine. If I used `Xterm` things worked fine as well. I noticed though, that the xfce terminal does not create a new pts session, and the results of `who` showed only myself as tty1. However, trying to `write` or `wall` to tty1 here was no dice. ssh'ing from somewhere else, or using `screen` within the xfce terminal gave me a virtual pts, which could be written to.

I did note with `w` that the user on tty1 was running `xinit /home/mmes/.xinitrc -- /etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc :0 vt1 -auth/`yadayada all the time. This led me to believe that somehow the xfce terminal is sending commands through the x server somehow, without using a session of its own?

This situation has kind of baffled me, and I would love to hear thoughts why from someone who knows how these graphical terminal emulators actually work, as well as if they know how to `write` or `wall` messages there.